# Sharing data between Signal Handler and Program in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

How do you share data between a signal handler and the main process of running program?

From searching it looks like it isn't possible but this can't be correct because it would make signals pointless.

Comment: Are you limited to strictly the C standard, or in a POSIX environment where there's a lot more options?

Comment: The normal way is to use global variables.

Comment: Use global `volatile sig_atomic_t` variables. https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/SIG31-C.+Do+not+access+shared+objects+in+signal+handlers

Comment: How do you prevent the handler from interrupting a reas/write request? The atomic variable used?

Comment: @FourierFlux In general, you can't prevent a signal from interrupting any call. **Some** calls can be restarted on POSIX systems if you use `sigaction()` and set the `SA_RESTART` flag. Some calls will be interrupted no matter if the `SA_RESTART` flag is set or not.  More concerning is a signal handler that has data that it needs to share - signal handlers are very bad places to do processing of any substantial amounts of data as they run completely asynchronously from the rest of the process.  Signal handlers also can only call async-signal-safe functions, limiting them significantly.

Comment: There isn't much data that you _can_ share.  In general, you know which signal was sent; you could determine the time at which the handler was called; and there's not much more.  If you're using POSIX and [`sigaction()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html), you can get some extra information using `SA_SIGINFO`.  See [Signal Concepts](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) for more information, and also the [`<signal.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) header.

Comment: A signal handler can really only communicate with the rest of the process via file scope variables — either accessible only within a single file (`static`) or across file (global — `extern`).  There is no way to pass a variable (e.g. a pointer to custom data) to the signal handler via the call made by the o/s to the signal handler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler *There is no way to pass a variable (e.g. a pointer to custom data) to the signal handler via the call made by the o/s to the signal handler.* Actually, there is on Linux/posix systems (a `SA_SIGINFO` handler and `sigqueue()`). That's one reason I asked what restrictions OP is under.

Comment: @Shawn: Hmmm — yes, I see [`sigqueue()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigqueue.html) does allow the sending of the data from a `union sigval`.  Note that using `union sigval` is limited: POSIX only says that the shall be an `int` or a `void *` members in the union (and so does Linux).  Passing a pointer between processes would be fraught; between threads in the current process might be useful.  The `SA_SIGINFO` flag (which I did mention) will be key to being able to get any extra data.  But it remains true that signals are a very limited IPC mechanism.